# How to paraphrase "In other words" shortly and formally?

Tags: paraphrasing

In a writing piece, after writing " The index witnessed a decrease last week. It means that the value of our stock fell", I normally paraphrase to "The index witnessed a decrease last week. In other words, the value of our stock fell". But it seems quite long to me.

Could you give me some formal examples to replace "In another word" in this case?

Comment: Is "witness" a verb?  You probalby want it to be in the past tense "witnessed"

Comment: @JamesK witness is a verb surely (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/witness)  and I edited my question. Thank you for your correction

Comment: There really is not enough context. i. e. **can replace it**.

Comment: @Lambie , it should be that "There really is not enough context. **i. e. we can replace it** " because after i.e. should be a full sentence right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quite formal style is to use no linking phrase and semicolons

> The index witnessed a decrease last week; the value of our stock fell.

There are some expressions like ", which is to say," and a couple of Latin abbreviations "viz." and "sc." that are sometimes used in legal documents.

But in simple clear language "In other words" is clear, and not informal.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is so little context, it is hard to tell how to shorten this.

> Last week's decrease in the index caused our stock's price to fall.

That is twelve words rather than sixteen, a shortening of 25%. Moreover, it is straight English without Latin abbreviations. My feeling is that whenever you feel the need to say "in short" about a mere sentence, the sentence itself is verbose or vague.

That, however, may not be exactly what you mean. For most stocks, the price is not determined solely by an index. Few if any stocks have a beta of 1 day in, day out. Perhaps you meant

> Our stock's price declined last week, in line with the index.

Without knowing what precise thought you mean to convey, it is impossible to know precisely how to express that thought more concisely.

Comment: Thank Jeff. First, I think that it is not cause and consequence so "Last week's decrease in the index caused our stock's price to fall." seems not really appropriate. I mean. Two sentences in my example are different ways of explaining the same thing.

Comment: My point was that your sentences make no sense unless there is a cause and effect relationship. There is a correlation among the prices of stocks, which is why I proposed the “in line with” alternative. What you literally say in your sentences is that a decline in an index necessarily results in a decline in the price of a specific stock. There might be a case where that is true, but it is false in most cases. Why should I invest in this stock if it is a slave to an index? Easier to invest in Vanguard.